# How to change Firefox debugger font size

Tags: firefox, fonts, debugging

It's too small to read.

Bug report is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143119

Notice: it's not about Firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox 27, Codemirror is now deployed as the default code editor:

> Codemirror
>
> Codemirror is a popular HTML5-based code editor component used on web sites. It is customizable and theme-able. The Firefox Devtools now use CodeMirror in various places: Style editor, Debugger, Inspector (Edit as HTML) and Scratchpad.
>
> From the Option panel, the user can select which theme to use (dark or light).

Source: [Firefox Developer Tools: Episode 27 – Edit as HTML, Codemirror & more](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/11/firefox-developer-tools-episode-27-edit-as-html-codemirror-more/)

---

This works for me in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profile-name/chrome/userChrome.css`.

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document regexp("chrome://browser/content/devtools/.*"){
* { font-size: 20px !important }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround for me was changing DPI value in KDE font settings. Now all other fonts are too big but at least I can read the debugger.

Comment: I think your correct edit was rejected because I was editing to add extra info. Sorry about that. I made the edit you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create `userChrome.css` in:

`/usr/lib/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/` (32 bit)

`/usr/lib64/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/` (64 bit)

It worked for me when I created `userChrome.css` in `/usr/lib64/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/` folder. This should also make your changes global.